# Static variable initialization in java

Tags: java, class, static

Consider the following code :

```
  public class TestClass 
    {
      int j=10;
      static int h=j;

      TestClass()
      {

          System.out.println(h);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          TestClass obj= new TestClass();       


      }

    }
```

Why this generates error even when  i have already declared j above h .

Comment: Take the error and google it.

Comment: Take it and error the google.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are mixing static declarations with instance variable declarations (which is pretty clear from the error message *Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field j*). Change the first initialization to

```
static int j = 10;
```

and your code compiles just fine.